# Can we have two or more classes in a Laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, solid-principles

Considering Interface Segregation Principle, which is one among the most “talked about” principles of Object Oriented Programming - SOLID principles, I was wondering if it were possible to have two different classes in a single Laravel controller? For example:

```
  <?php

    namespace ...;

    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

    interface VehicleInterface
    {
      public function ...
    }

    class CarController extends Controller implements VehicleInterface
    {
       ...
    }

    class ElectricCar implements VehicleInterface
    { 
       ...
    }
```

Comment: It is `recommended` to have only one class per file although in php you can make workarounds.

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa, I was just wondering the possibility in a situation where your application is just a simple one

Comment: First thought: It does not look correct to me that a CarController and an ElectricCar share one interface.

Comment: @GhostGambler, they could share common methods/functions such as shiftGear(), steer(), accelerate(), decelerate() amongst others

Comment: @DunsinOlubobokun one small application can become a big messy one in a year. If you want to make `Spaghetti code` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code do what you want but it is not ok.

Comment: @DunsinOlubobokun But a CarController does not belong to a single car, it needs a parameter to access a specific car, maybe a CarRepository to access Cars at all. The Car itself is one single Car. I do not think that these interfaces have anything in common. They also have a different meaning: The Car interface models a Car, which has gears, which can be accelerated, on the other hand the CarController handles Cars or a single car providing an interface to an abstract construct.

Comment: I seem to see your point, thanks for your contribution @GhostGambler

Answer (score 6):

Technically you can have multiple classes in the same file.

With Laravel (or any framework), not really, if you want to use its autoloader, as classname = filename is the convention.

Also, a controller is what handles requests. You can load as many instances of your different classes inside a controller function. But **defining** other classes inside the controller file is not what you're supposed to do, at all.

Answer (score 3):

This question has at least two problems:

1. I do not think that `ElectricCar` and `CarController` should share the same interface. The `ElectricCar` models a car, possibly with methods like `accelerateTo(120mph)` whereas the `CarController` maybe has methods like `accelerateCarTo(Car5, 120mph)`. They are also used with a different meaning: The `ElectricCar` models one single car, whereas the `CarController` manages access to a single or multiple cars, which is also called from a abstract construct modeling an application flow.
2. The *interface segregation principle* does not speak about classes, so the question is ill-formed in the first place. **The interface segregation principle says that one interface**(!) specifying multiple use cases **should be broken up into multiple interfaces**(!) called *role interfaces*, each fulfilling exactly one use case. For example, an interface modeling an ATM with methods like `deposit()` and `withdraw()` should be split up into two interfaces each only fulfilling one of these functions. The goal is that a dependent entity must only use and see the parts it really requires.